# Internet is extremely slow on Ubuntu; fine on Windows?

Tags: wireless

I have a desktop I am dual-booting with Windows/Ubuntu. In Windows, I'm getting around 8-12 mb/s, and in Ubuntu I'm currently getting ~.1 mb/s. I have a Belkin F7D1101 USB Wireless Adapter. I have the latest version of Ubuntu installed.

I'm not really sure what other information would be needed in order to help me, so comment if you need some info on my system.

Comment: `I'm getting around 8-12 mb/s, and in Ubuntu I'm currently getting ~.1 mb/s.` I assume you did the test using the same website and just after doing it on Windows, and without having any other software opened. Use `speedtest.net` or other similar website to see if there's indeed a problem with your internet connection or only with the connection with the specific website you used to do the speed test.

Answer (score 0):

A little googling found this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1522815&highlight=Belkin+F7D1101

follow those directions exactly and you should be up and running with it.

Comment: None of those instructions worked for me, I'm assuming because they were intended for Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Were you able to get through all of the steps without any problems? They were working for people up to 12.04 and it didn't seem like anyone tried them after that.

Comment: Well, yes, but whenever I do the `sudo gedit`, it creates a new file with the specified file name, as opposed to opening it.

Comment: Yes, the instructions say the files are likely empty. Just keep following them.

Comment: I followed the instructions all the way through and no luck :(

Comment: Did you have trouble with any of the steps or did something not work?

Comment: Can you tell me what the output of `sudo modprobe -v r8712u` is?